# MySQL: Get records from specific date and group the specific station each hour

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `call_log` (
  `call_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `call_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `caller` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name_recording_url` varchar(123) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `forwarded_from` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `called_number` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_to_phone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `market` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `station` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `distributor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `distributor_phone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `answered` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `mode` enum('Live','Test') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`call_id`)
)
```

So, I would like to populate the station in distinct time with total calls.

So for example, we have station ABCD and ASDF. ABCD has 30 records, ASDF has 10 records. I want to get their records each hour.

Example output would be:

```
station    call_time(H)     total_call
ABCD       10               5               // ABCD has 5 calls at 10am
ABCD       12               20              // ABCD has 20 calls at 12pm
ABCD       15               5               // ABCD has 5 calls at 3pm
ASDF       08               4               // ASDF has 4 calls at 8am
ASDF       05               2               // ASDF has 2 calls at 5pm
ASDF       13               2               // ASDF has 2 calls at 1pm
ASDF       22               2               // ASDF has 2 calls at 10pm
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT station, HOUR(call_time) as call_time(H), COUNT(call_id) AS total_call
FROM call_log
GROUP BY station, HOUR(call_time)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT station, HOUR(call_time), COUNT(call_id) AS total_call
FROM call_log
GROUP BY station, HOUR(call_time)
```

Comment: I have to set @SashiKant as answer because of the alias call_time(H).